# Iterate through the list and insert number plus 1 to the next position of the list

Tags: java, list, loops

I'm doing a Java practice which ask me to iterate through each number in the arraylist and for each number, insert the number plus one to the next position of the list. Return the resulting list after finished. If there is no elements in the provided list, directly throw IllegalArgumentException.

```
public class ListAddNPlusOne {
    public static ArrayList<Integer> addNPlusOne(ArrayList<Integer> numbers) 
    {
        if(numbers.size() == 0) 
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        
        int result;
        
        for (int num : numbers){
            result += num;
        } 

    }
}
```

This is the code I have so far. I did the throw exception and iterate through the list, I add 1 to the found integer of that list. But I don't know how to return the newest list, I'm also not sure if my thinking is right on this. Thanks for any help/ hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be confused as to the requirements. I can't tell why you have `result`. First, I would test for `null` and I would prefer `isEmpty()` to `.size() == 0`. Next, create new `ArrayList` to store the values you want to return. Then, iterate the values in `numbers`. For each `num` add that to the new `ArrayList` (and then add that `+ 1`). Finally return the new `ArrayList`. Like,

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> addNPlusOne(ArrayList<Integer> numbers) {
    if (numbers == null || numbers.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Integer num : numbers) {
        al.add(num);
        al.add(num + 1);
    }
    return al;
}
```

Without creating a new `ArrayList` using a [`ListIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) like

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> addNPlusOne(ArrayList<Integer> numbers) {
    if (numbers == null || numbers.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    ListIterator<Integer> li = numbers.listIterator();
    while (li.hasNext()) {
        int v = li.next();
        li.add(v + 1);
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

Comment: Can I directly add the element in the numbers list and not to create a new arraylist? Is it possible?

Comment: @HY2000 Sure. Just not easy. And the requirements say *Return the resulting list after finished*